# Loop through Realm Object fields in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loops

I have a Realm Object

```
class CoursesModel: Object {

dynamic var courseName = ""
dynamic var par3Field = 0
dynamic var par4Field = 0
dynamic var par5Field = 0
```

}

When somebody enters the course name I want to check whether it already exists before writing it to Realm.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong because it doesn't seem to loop through.

```
class func compareCourse(name : String) -> Bool {

    let c = name

    do
    {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let course = realm.objects(CoursesModel)

        for course in course {
            if course == c {
                print("course = \(course)")
                print("c = \(c)")

                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        // return nil
    }

    return false
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - WORKING CODE HERE

```
class func compareCourse(name : String) -> Bool {

    let c = name

    do
    {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let course = realm.objects(CoursesModel)

        for course in course {
            let a = course.courseName
            print("Model Course = \(a)")
            print("Passed Course = \(c)")
            if a == c {
                return true
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // return nil
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning in both branches of the loop, which immediately exits out of the function. You do not want to return false on the first failure, but only after all have failed (I think).

Comment: Hi Robert. Yes that is what it looks like to me so there is something wrong in the way the loop is constructed. I cannot figure out what though. If I print course after for line I only get the first course name.

Comment: Delete the else branch altogether

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks. It's working now, i.e. looping through the whole Model. However the constant course still refers to the whole model and not just the course name which I am actually after. Is there a way to interrogate only the course name? The print looks like this - c = g
a = CoursesModel {
 courseName = west;
 par3Field = 2;
 par4Field = 3;
 par5Field = 6;

Comment: Fixed it. Working code edited above. Thanks for the pointers.